# MongoDB: Select all elements where 2 fields have the same date

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection like this:

```
 {
     _id: ObjectId("53c4000f821bc31e3ec90140"),
     foo: "bar",
     created: ISODate("2014-07-09T02:15:49.000+02:00"),
     updated: ISODate("2014-07-09T02:15:49.000+02:00")
 },
 {
     _id: ObjectId("53c4000f821bc4dw3ec90140"),
     foo: "bar",
     created: ISODate("2014-07-09T02:15:49.000+02:00"),
     updated: ISODate("2014-07-09T02:19:49.000+02:00")
 },
```

Now I want to **select all elements of the collection where created == updated**. In this example the query should return only the first element.

I tried this:
`db.foo.find( {$where: "this.created == this.updated"})` but I get no results :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Object comparisons don't work like that in JavaScript. You need to compare a "value" and not the whole object:

```
 db.foo.find(function(){ return this.created.valueOf() == this.updated.valueOf() })
```

So the `.valueOf()` is the key here. And that is just a shorthand for [**`$where`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) when you have no other conditions.